# Unlocked Package - Modify Custom Metadata Type in Subscriber Org

Tags: managed-package, unmanaged-package, unlocked-package, custom-metadata

I created an Unlocked Package that contains a Custom Metadata Type (CMT). When I install this package inside an org, I would like to give access to admins to edit this deployed CMT (e.g. - create a new field on it).

I can do this just fine with Custom Objects deployed with my Unlocked Package, but when somebody tries to create a new field on the CMT they receive the following error:

> **Cannot create fields on installed managed custom metadata type.**
>
> You can't create custom fields on installed managed custom metadata types.

The error says that the CMT is **managed**, but I was of the impression that Unlocked Packages are not Managed - I know they can be upgraded, but they can also be freely changed directly in a subscriber org.

Here's my CMT metadata:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CustomObject xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <description>Does something</description>
    <label>Setting</label>
    <pluralLabel>Settings</pluralLabel>
    <visibility>Public</visibility>
</CustomObject>
```

Am I missing a setting on my package or on the CMT that would allow it to be modified directly in a subscriber org?

Comment: What's the visibility on the metadata object and the Field managebility of the metadata fields, and are the records Protected?

Comment: The visibility is `public`, you can see it in the provided metadata snippet in the question above. There's no records deployed with the package. I'm not sure where to check the "field manageability"?

Comment: @manjit5190 just got back on my laptop and checked the field manageability, it is set to `SubscriberControlled`, so should be fine.

Comment: @smukov have u found a solution for this? I am also struck with the same issue